# Tag synonym request: [gnome3] -> [gnome3.4]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there a real changes [gnome3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome3) and [gnome3.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome3.4) for to be tag synonyms?

Comment: Should be the other way around no?